# Need Help Coding Google Chrome Extension (Beginner)

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, selenium, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to create a simple google chrome extension with  2 or 3 browser actions. I've been using selenium IDE to record the steps through Firefox I want to use. However, I don't know how to take those steps and put them into a coding language for Google Chrome in a .json so I can upload. I'm a beginner and have little coding knowledge, if someone could lead me in the right direction that would be great. Thanks for your time!

Comment: Then you need to create 2 or 3 Chrome extensions. Each extension can have one button at most.

Answer (score 0):

To begin, you will need some basic knowledge of JavaScript (and possibly HTML and CSS) for experimenting and asking further questions. These are the tools used to build Chrome extensions.

Here are some good places to learn from:

- [Khan Academy - Intro to JS](https://www.khanacademy.org/computing/computer-programming/programming)
- [Codecademy - JavaScript track](http://www.codecademy.com/en/tracks/javascript)

After that, [IBM's tutorial](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/os-extendchrome/) for Chrome extensions is a must-read.

Further on down the line, there are tools that make the process of developing extensions easier and/or faster, etc. such as [Extension Maker](http://extensionmaker.com/) and [Crossrider](https://crossrider.com/).

Enjoy!